# How to generate a CAPTCHA?

Tags: captcha

I want to generate my own CAPTCHA. I am using PIL library of Python to generate an image. I would like to know how should the image be (i.e. numbers with weird font style or some mathematical calculation shown in an image (for example: 5x8))

How can I validate it with the user input? - Can I store it in a variable to check it later with the user input, will it be safe or is this vulnerable to attack?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Essentially you are just asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: Have you reviewed the design of established CAPTCHA APIs?

Comment: Why would you want to? Research the topic, beginning with some of the posts here, and you'll see that CAPTCHA has been proven, for most scenarios, to be of little value. Also, there are plenty of existing libraries and services - so, considering that you're asking how to do it, I would assume that you don't necessarily have a better idea than they do. On the other hand, if you're doing it solely for education, then still - there are better ways to do so.

Comment: @AviD My aim is just to get some knowledge about captcha. I will research on the topic and will ask any of my doubts here. Thank You.